# Maximum probability of winning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am very new to asking questions so please comment if any additional clarifications are required on the question and I will edit the question likewise. I am stuck with this following question.

An archer wants to score **exactly** **N points** to win a tournament and he has last set of **A arrows** left with him. He has an option to discard the arrow (and registering a zero for that shot) or pick any of the **K bows** for that particular shot and take his shot. It is possible to score in between the range of 0 to 5 for a particular shot. Given probability distribution of scoring 0 to 5 points with each of the K bows, calculate the probability of winning considering that the archer maximizes his chance of winning.

The approach that I was trying here is to find total number of ways possible to achieve N points with A arrows, I am confused about what should I do after getting the maximum probabilities of all the possible ways I can achieve N points using A arrows? How do I combine them? Or if my approach to the question is wrong?

I thank you for your help!

Comment: Work from the back.  For each possible score on the fourth round, which bow should he pick, and what is his probability of winning?  Now if we knew the probabilities of having each score on the fourth round, we'd be able to compute the expectation.  So, go back to the third round and do the same thing.  Now we need to know the probabilities of each score on the third round, so we go back to the second round.  On the first round, we know that the score is $0$, so we can work forward.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you helping me! Is there any similar kind of question someplace online where I can see and refer the solution from? Actually I am very new to probability theory and not quite sure how do I compute the expectation values. It would be of great help if you can show me the calculations for the above example as well. Thanks much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @hacker_panda I got about .85 by starting with Bow 2 (not exactly .854), so I'm not sure if it's right. But if you want to see, I can post it. (But it's messy).

Comment: @Jellyfish 0.85 is very close! I'd definitely love to see the solution. Could you please post it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If you have zero points, use Bow 1. If you have one or two points, use Bow 2. If you have three points, you're a winner. Draw the complete tree (as @Jellyfish shows) and add up the wins. With this strategy, you get the win probability of $0.8548$

Comment: @DanielMathias The answer is still coming far off than 0.8548. Can you please help with the tree as JellyFish shows? I am getting confused between making decisions between bow 1 and bow 2. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was farther off than I thought, but hopefully this can give you some kind of idea and either check that I made all the right decisions or start with Bow 1. This calculates the probability to $0.7808$

[image]

The correct tree as suggested in the comments. I leave to you to fill in the probabilities (multiply the probabilities along each branch after you have filled them in and them sum them all up):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will surely check this solution out and see if I get any ideas to start with Bow 1 and try out all possible combinations! I really appreciate all the help. Please let me know in case you figure out the answer as well. Cheers!

Comment: Neither of the bows picked as the starting bow is giving the answer 0.8548 :( Any idea what else can be done?

Comment: @hacker_panda I got .8548 using the method suggested int he comments. It will take me some minutes to draw the tree

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Got the correct answer now. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, note that there is no gain in discarding the arrow unless you have exactly $3$ points.  If you have fewer than $3$ points, you have to take another shot, and you might as well take it now as later.

For $k=1,2,3,4$ and $s=01,2,3$, let $p_k(s)$ be the probability that the archer wins if he starts round $k$ with exactly $s$ points, and makes the optimal decisions from then on.

First take $k = 4$.  If $s=0$, the archer needs $3$ points, so he will choose bow $1$, and will win with probability $\frac4{10}$.

If $s=1$, the archer needs $2$ points, and has no chance with either bow.

If $s=2$, he chooses bow $2$ and wins with probability $\frac{8}{10}$.

If $s= 3$, he doesn't use arrow $4$, and he surely wins.

That is, $$\begin{align}
p_4(0) &= \frac25\\
p_4(1) &=0\\
p_4(2)&=\frac45\\
p_4(3)&=1
\end{align}$$

Now consider $k=3$.

When $s=0,$  if the archer chooses bow $1$, his probability of success is $$\frac3{10}\cdot\frac25+\frac3{10}\cdot0+\frac4{10}\cdot1=\frac{13}{25},$$
and if he chooses bow $2$, the probability of winning is $$\frac1{10}\cdot\frac25+\frac8{10}\cdot0+\frac1{10}\cdot1=\frac{7}{50}$$
Therefore, he chooses bow $1$ and $p_3(0) = \frac{13}{25}$.

If $s=1$, bow $1$ gives $$
\frac3{10}\cdot0+\frac3{10}\cdot\frac45+\frac4{10}\cdot0=\frac4{25}$$
and bow $2$ gives$$
\frac1{10}\cdot0+\frac8{10}\cdot\frac45+\frac1{10}\cdot0=\frac{16}{25}$$
In each case, the last term comes from the case where he has $4$ aggregate points, and no chance of winning.  We ignore this case from now on.

If $s=2$, we only need to consider the cases where he scores $0$ points or $1$ point.  Bow $1$ gives $$
\frac3{10}\cdot\frac45+\frac3{10}\cdot1=\frac{27}{50}$$ and bow $2$ gives $$
\frac1{10}\cdot\frac45+\frac8{10}\cdot1=\frac{22}{25}$$

In summary, $$\begin{align}
p_3(0)&=\frac{13}{25}\\
p_3(1)&=\frac{16}{25}\\
p_3(2)&=\frac{22}{25}\\
p_3(3)&=1
\end{align}$$

Now for the case $k=2$.

When $s=0$, bow $1$ gives
$$\frac3{10}\cdot\frac{13}{25}+\frac3{10}\cdot\frac{16}{25}+\frac{4}{10}\cdot1=\frac{187}{250}$$
and bow $2$ gives
$$\frac1{10}\cdot\frac{13}{25}+\frac8{10}\cdot\frac{16}{25}+\frac1{10}\cdot1=\frac{166}{250}$$

When $s=1$,bow $1$ gives $$
\frac3{10}\cdot\frac{16}{25}+\frac3{10}\cdot\frac{22}{25}=\frac{57}{125}$$
and bow $2$ gives$$
\frac1{10}\cdot\frac{16}{25}+\frac8{10}\cdot\frac{22}{25}=\frac{96}{125}$$
When $s=2$, bow $1$ gives $$
\frac3{10}\cdot\frac{22}{25}+\frac3{10}\cdot1=\frac{141}{250}$$ and bow $2$ gives $$
\frac1{10}\cdot\frac{22}{25}+\frac8{10}\cdot1=\frac{111}{125}$$
In summary, $$\begin{align}
p_2(0)&=\frac{187}{250}\\
p_2(1)&=\frac{96}{125}\\
p_2(2)&=\frac{111}{125}\\
p_2(3)&=1
\end{align}$$

Now for $k=1$.

We start round $1$ with $0$ points, so
bow $1$ gives $$
\frac3{10}\cdot\frac{187}{250}+\frac3{10}\cdot\frac{96}{125}+\frac4{10}\cdot1=\frac{2137}{2500}$$
and bow $2$ gives$$
\frac1{10}\cdot\frac{187}{250}+\frac8{10}\cdot\frac{96}{125}+\frac1{10}\cdot1=\frac{1973}{2500}$$

so the archer should use bow $1$ in the first round, and his probability of winning is $$\frac{2137}{2500}=\boxed{.8548}$$

I originally made some errors in this calculation, and wrote a little python script to get the correct probabilities, so that I could check them as I went.

In case you're interested, here's the script

```
from fractions import Fraction

    bow1 = {0:Fraction(3,10),
            1:Fraction(3,10),
            3:Fraction(4,10), 2:0}
    bow2 ={0:Fraction(1,10),
           1:Fraction(8,10),
           3:Fraction(1,10), 2:0}
    
    class pDict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            k, s = key
            if s == 3:
                return 1
            if s > 3:
                return 0
            if k > 4:
                return 0
            
    p = pDict()
    for k in range(4,0,-1):
        for s in range(3):
            p[k,s] = max(sum(b[t]*p[k+1,t+s] 
                       for t in range(4)) 
                         for b in (bow1,bow2))
            
    print(f'Probability of success {p[1,0]}\n')
    for k in range(4,1,-1):
        for s in range(3):
            print(f'p[{k},s] {p[k,s]}')
        print()
```

I hope the method is clear.  In principle, we draw the entire tree, showing all possibilities.  There are two kinds of nodes, square nodes, say  where we choose a bow, and round nodes where we score $0,\ 1,\text{ or }3$.  Working from the bottom up, we assign values to the squares nodes, representing the probability of success if we choose the better bow.  We use the values assigned to the square nodes at one level to compute the values of the square nodes at the next higher level.

It's hard to draw the picture.  It's probably easiest to draw a succession of trees, starting with round $4$ and going backwards.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to answer the question. The script really helped me learn more about the question. Thanks much!

Comment: @hacker_panda My pleasure.  I think the script is even more instructive, and certainly more elegant, if it's written to use a recursive function rather than a dict but  I wanted to mimic the pencil-and-paper calculations.  You might want to reimplement the script using recursion.  If you do, I recommend the lru_cache decorator from the functools module.  Not necessary for this tiny problem, but good practice.